# How do I create a new thread to make pcap_loop() and gtk_main() compatible?

Tags: c, gtk, multithreading, pcap

These two functions are both infinite loops,

and the programe hangs once called in the same thread.

```
gtk_main(); 
...
pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);
```

When I click the "start" button,I want `pcap` to **start** working;And if I press the "stop" button,`pcap` **stop**.

How do I create a child thread and run `pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, your problem is that both GTK+ and
libpcap are organized around events fired from a main loop. Without
looking through the documentation, I don't know about GTK+, but there
is another mode of operation for libpcap: You can use `pcap_next()` or
`pcap_next_ex()` without giving up control over your program flow.

It should be possible to register a function that periodically calls
one of these two functions using `g_timeout_add()` or `g_idle_add()`,
removing the need to mess around with threads and mutex mechanisms
altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for `g_thread_create()`. Also read [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDK_Threads.html) and [this blog post](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness.html) for more information on multithreaded GTK programs.

Basically you'll want to call `gtk_main()` first when you've built your user interface and started your program. Then in the callback for the "start" button, create a new thread with `g_thread_create()` in which you call `pcap_loop()`.

The "stop" button is a little more difficult since GLib doesn't allow you to interrupt a thread from a different thread. You'll have to create some signaling mechanism; for example, a boolean abort flag protected by a `GMutex`. In your stop button callback, lock the flag with `g_mutex_lock()`, set it, and unlock it with `g_mutex_unlock()`. In your `packet_handler`, also lock the flag, read it, and unlock it. If the flag was set, then call whatever it is you call to make pcap break out of the loop.

Comment: How can I output something into `gtk_text_view`(main thread) from the thread(child thread) created by `g_thread_create()`?

Comment: Read the documentation about threads in GTK. You can call GTK functions from the child thread, as long as you _protect_ them by surrounding the GTK calls with `gdk_threads_enter()` and `gdk_threads_leave()`.