# Why the gtk windows hangs?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk

```
void forloop2()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        printf("forloop2\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    GtkWidget *window;
    g_thread_init(NULL);
    gdk_threads_init();
    g_thread_create((GThreadFunc)forloop2, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

It seems the created thread affects `gtk_window_new`(my programe hangs here),

how do I do it correctly?

**UPDATE**

fixed by `gdk_threads_enter/leave`

Comment: It works fine for me.  I added `gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), gtk_entry_new ());` there to test that window works, and it does.

Comment: Do you mean it works without `gdk_threads_enter/leave`, really?

Comment: That's the point with multithreading bugs; they can work perfectly fine on one system and crash horribly on the next.

Comment: You should add an aswer with your solution and then accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From the GDK docs:

> You must also surround any calls to GTK+ not made within a signal handler with a gdk_threads_enter()/gdk_threads_leave() pair.

See http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Threads.html#gdk-Threads.description

Comment: See also this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793293/how-do-i-create-a-new-thread-to-make-pcap-loop-and-gtk-main-compatible/2793644#2793644